# Count all subsets with given sum for a linked list

Tags: c++, algorithm, linked-list, dynamic-programming

Given a Linked List of numbers (unsorted) find total combinations of numbers that give sum=K.

The only solution I can think of is converting my linked list to an array and then proceed via the count subset sum algorithm.

Is there some better approach to this problem?

Comment: There is no need to have rewritten it as an array to do the count subset sum algorithm.  But yes, that is the right approach.

Comment: But I can't randomly access elements in a linked list, so how would I do it?

Comment: Why do you need random access? You can calculate the DP table one column at a time. And for each column, you need only a single list entry.

Comment: I don't quite understand. Would you explain it? The subset algorithm I know maintains the count with the formula go[i][j] = go[i-1][j-a[i-1]] + go[i][j] for every row and column in my DP table go[][]. So with linked list, should I keep a pointer pointing to the previous elements, the (i-1)th element, and a pointer to the current element?

Comment: Exactly. Start by calculating `go[0][j]` (initialize). Then look at the first list element (`a[0]`) and calculate all `go[1][j]`. Then look at the next list element (`a[1]`) and calculate `go[2][j]`. Continue until you are done.

Comment: Got it. Thanks man!